# why linux id command give me different info about the same account?

Tags: linux

I am using ubuntu 13.04. 
And I wonder why I get different groups info when using id command with/without account.

when I type

```
$id user1
uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(user1) groups=1000(user1),1001(user2)
```

but when I type

```
$id
uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(use1) groups=1000(user1),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

why use "id" command only cannot list my  supplementary group?

by the way, following is one entry of my /etc/group :

```
user2:x:1001:user1
```

Any help ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've edited /etc/group but haven't logged off and back on again. I suggest starting a new shell, and trying `id` again.

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks! It gives me the same answer after I log off and back on again. 
So. does it mean that I have to log off and back on again every time when I update /etc/group or /etc/passwd ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The id information for your current session is cached, in effect.